# Parse json string in php

Tags: php, json

```
    {
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "New Delhi",
               "short_name" : "New Delhi",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "West Delhi",
               "short_name" : "West Delhi",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Delhi",
               "short_name" : "DL",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "India",
               "short_name" : "IN",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "New Delhi, Delhi, India",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 28.88981589999999,
                  "lng" : 77.34181459999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 28.4010669,
                  "lng" : 76.8396999
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 28.635308,
               "lng" : 77.22496
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 28.88981589999999,
                  "lng" : 77.34181459999999
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 28.4010669,
                  "lng" : 76.8396999
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

How do i parse the above json string with php

Trying the following code out but no success:

```
   $url = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Delhi&sensor=true");


     $json = json_decode($url);


foreach($json->results as $item) {
        $location_item = array(
            'address' => $item->formatted_address,

        );

    }
```

I am getting blank page the code doesn't work please help i am new to php

Comment: Your code works fine for me. What are you doing with `$this->address`?

Comment: Initiate $address = array() first. and if this is not a class then $this->address should generate and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am getting blank page the code doesn't work please help i am new to
>   php

Your code actually works , maybe you are not printing the data that is why you are getting a blank page.

### Tested

```
<?php
$url = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Delhi&sensor=true");
$json = json_decode($url);
foreach($json->results as $item) {
    $location_item = array(
        'address' => $item->formatted_address,

    );

}

print_r($location_item);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
Array
(
    [address] => New Delhi, Delhi, India
)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work, `location_item` is not in the scope

Comment: @demonking, Scope ? `location_item` is not under any function.

Comment: @demonking: This would work because PHP variable "scope rule" doesn't not work for this script as it not dealing with a function or class instance.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, sorry, my mistake!

Comment: How do i print as a string and not an array?

Comment: @vini, Replace `print_r($location_item);` with `echo $location_item['address'];`

Comment: im wondering, why do people think `if` or `for` and `foreach` should create a scope ...

Comment: how do we parse the first short_name and lat and long under the location

Comment: @vini, Could you open an another question as it can't be explained here fully.